# How can I safely measure the width which a node will have, when the style to be applied may alter the font?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, errors, tikz-styles, dimensions

I want to find the width that a node will have when it is later constructed. The width depends on the node's content and the style applied to the node. The style may alter the font using the `font` key.

My attempt was to use `\settowidth` on a TikZ picture containing just the node, with the style applied but `inner sep` set to zero. This works fine if the style used is something like `red` or `text opacity=.1` or, even,`fill=colour@background`. But if the user adds `font=\scriptsize` to the style, then compilation fails with a fatal error.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\newlength\mylength
\tikzset{%
  my code/.code={%
    \settowidth\mylength{\tikz{\node[my style] {something};}}%
    \draw (0,0) -- +(\mylength,0);
  },
  my style/.style={red},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my code,
  ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my style/.style={font=\normalfont},% or font=\scriptszie or font=\itshape or whatever
    my code,
  ]% this is line 119 mentioned in the error message
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the error in all its lethal glory:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\pgf@selectfontorig ->\pgf@selectfontorig 
                                          \nullfont 
l.119   ]

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Now `\nullfont` looks clearly dodgy, but I'm not sure why TikZ would be falling through to it.

In any case, my approach is clearly far too simple-minded.

What is the cause of the error and how can it be avoided?

Comment: If I just do `\settowidth{\node ...}` I don't get errors, but is that really correct?

Comment: I get a width of zero, of course, regardless of content, so I could just as well use `0pt` and be done with it ;).

Comment: In a tikzpicture, outside of nodes, the default font is `\nullfont` (cf. p.124, pgfmanual v3.0.1a).

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `calc` library and a very distant scope with `overlay` key:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{%
  my code/.code={%
    \begin{scope}[overlay]
      \node[my style,anchor=west] (a) at (-16000pt,0) {something};
      \path let \p1 = (a.east), \p2 = (a.west), \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,0)}
      in \pgfextra{\xdef\mygloballenght{\n1}};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[black] (0,0) -- +(\mygloballenght,0);
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my style/.style={red,font=\Large}]
  \draw[red] (0,1) -- (2,1);
  \tikzset{my code}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my style/.style={font=\normalfont}]
  \draw[red] (0,1) -- (2,1);
  \tikzset{my code}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Could you explain why `veclen` is needed? Why isn't this just like using `\x2-\x1`? Do you by any chance know why the manual says it is possible to 'escape back' to normal typesetting but then fails to say anything about how to do so?!

Comment: @cfr I use `veclen` to  not to pay attention to the sign...! You may _escape back_ by using carefully the `pgfinterruptpicture` environment.

Comment: Not `abs()`? Or does that not work with dimensions? Thanks.

Comment: @cfr `abs` is another solution (because, here, the second coordinate is zero).

Comment: Thanks again. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. (I never use `veclen`. I do use `abs`, I guess.) `pgfinterruptpicture` is interesting.

Comment: `\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\newlength\mylength
\newsavebox\mybox
\tikzset{%
  my code/.code={\sbox\mybox{%
      \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}
        \tikz{\node[my style] {something};}
      \end{pgfinterruptpicture}}%
    \settowidth\mylength{\usebox\mybox}%
    \draw (0,0) -- +(\mylength,0) node [font=\normalsize] {b};
  },
  my style/.style={red},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [my style/.style={font=\Huge},my code ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [my style/.style={font=\tiny},my code]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` ...

Comment: ... seems to work but I have no idea if it is safe or not.